# Clean and build project error

Tags: java, netbeans

I build a project in Java using NetBeans but when I click on Clean and Build after few minutes it display below error:

```
-C:\Users\Asus\Documents\NetBeansProjects\prova\nbproject\build-impl.xml:990:
```

The following error occurred while executing this line:

```
-C:\Users\Asus\Documents\NetBeansProjects\prova\nbproject\build-impl.xml:834: copylibs doesn't support the "excludeFromCopy" attribute
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a well known bug in NetBeans, you can find the solution here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/codenameone-discussions/X_HMILMsw_Y

Comment: Nice , it has been very helpful , did not know of this error.